# comparing contents of a column to another data set

Tags: r, list

I am new to R and needed help to compare columns of content.

I ordered my first table in terms of a particular column. For this I used the following function:

```
 x = fread ("x.txt", sep = ";")
 x_order = x [order (x $ V3)]
```

I'm working with files that have some 5 million lines, only need to reduce this number.
One way would be to eliminate the data that is equal to a list of 10,450 items. That is, these 5 million lines I have a column with the same and different values to this list.

Any idea what I can do?

I tried to do this to my data but did not work!

```
##### Filter data: data that must remain
filter = read.csv ("filter.txt")
filter1 = data.frame (filter)

############# Dataset to be filtered
data = fread ("data.txt", sep = ";")
data1 = data.frame (date)

new_data = data1 [! data1 $ V5% in% filter] # allocate a variable in the amounts equal to the filter

write.table (new_data, "data_filter.txt", sep = ";")
```

If I want to see the data disponibilizei this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nau51en34xv394x/AAAWlkUwib0j0_xo47vYMh_Ja?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "negation of in-ness", if you will. By which I mean `!` on `%in%`. Here's a simple demo:

```
set.seed(1);
x <- data.frame(letters=sample(letters[1:10]),numbers=sample(1:10));
x;
##    letters numbers
## 1        c       3
## 2        d       2
## 3        e       6
## 4        g      10
## 5        b       5
## 6        h       7
## 7        i       8
## 8        f       4
## 9        j       1
## 10       a       9
eliminate <- sample(letters[1:10],3);
eliminate;
## [1] "j" "b" "f"
x[!x$letters%in%eliminate,];
##    letters numbers
## 1        c       3
## 2        d       2
## 3        e       6
## 4        g      10
## 6        h       7
## 7        i       8
## 10       a       9
```

This will work regardless of the ordering of the data.frame `x` and vector `eliminate`.